# tmp directory cleanup in centos

Tags: linux, tmp

Hi with a (bad) script of mine I filled up lots of files in /tmp folder. Now when I do ls in tmp folder it doesn't return anything (i waited for more than an hour). Hence I am not able to cleanup the directory. I tried reboot as well. I can see the tmpwatch is running but it is either too slow or not working at all.

Is there any (quick) way I can clean up /tmp files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
find /tmp !-user root -delete
```

you can add `-mtime <gracedays>` switch if you want and `cron` it

Answer (score 1):

If you have an idea of the filename structure you can do something like:

find . -name "stuff*" -exec rm {} \;

To clean up old php sessions in my tmp dir, I have
find . -name "sess_*" -atime +1h -exec rm {} \;
in a cron job.

If you're using rm, you might get an error that there are too many files, which is why

Comment: yes I have already tried it. But it doesn't even return anything

Comment: Well, it seems it is doing the job. But since there was no progress it gave me a feeling that it's stuck. Now, I gave find . -name "stuff*" -exec rm -vf {} \; and gives me the status. All good. Thanks for the help.